# Better way to get dictionary values that are strings in a list or a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
#the dictionary is 
mydict = {'fruits': 'banana, apple,grapefruit', 
'vegetables': 'tomato, potato,brocolli', 
'dry fruits': 'cashew, almond' }

#expected output can be either list or string

banana, apple,grapefruit,tomato,potato,brocolli,cashew,almond
```

what I have until now is to put the values in a list and iterate through each element
of the list and split each string

```
mydict = {'fruits': 'banana, apple,grapefruit', 
'vegetables': 'tomato, potato,brocolli', 
'dry fruits': 'cashew, almond' }
newlist = ''
mylist = list(mydict.values())
for ele in mylist:
    x = ele.replace(' ', '').strip(',')
    newlist = newlist + x +','
print(newlist)
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a list from the comma-separated values you could do this:

```
mydict = {'fruits': 'banana, apple,grapefruit',
          'vegetables': 'tomato, potato,brocolli',
          'dry fruits': 'cashew, almond'}

list_ = list(map(str.strip, ','.join(mydict.values()).split(',')))

print(list_)
```

**Output:**

```
['banana', 'apple', 'grapefruit', 'tomato', 'potato', 'brocolli', 'cashew', 'almond']
```

Answer (score 0):

For string, you can directly use the [`join`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-join-method/) method ( Which is commonly used to convert a list to a string).

And, for a list, you can loop through all the values and use the [`split`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/) method to make them into a list. then use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`strip`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) methods to remove unnecessary spaces from the string.

```py
mydict = {'fruits': 'banana, apple,grapefruit', 
'vegetables': 'tomato, potato,brocolli', 
'dry fruits': 'cashew, almond' }
# for string
mystring = ','.join(mydict.values())
print(f'String output = {mystring}')

# for list
mylist = []
for a in mydict.values():
    l = map(lambda e:e.strip(),a.split(','))
    mylist.extend(l)
print(f'list output = {mylist}')
```

#### OUTPUT

```
String output = banana, apple,grapefruit,tomato, potato,brocolli,cashew, almond
list output = ['banana', 'apple', 'grapefruit', 'tomato', 'potato', 'brocolli', 'cashew', 'almond']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
','.join(mydict.values())
```

what about just join them all?

Comment: How is this better than the existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict = {'fruits': 'banana, apple,grapefruit', 
'vegetables': 'tomato, potato,brocolli', 
'dry fruits': 'cashew, almond' }

l = [v for (k,v) in mydict.items()]
l = ','.join(l)
l = l.split(',')
l = [i.replace(' ', '') for i in l]

print(l)
```

Answer (score -1):

split values at `,` and add to new list `strip()` is to remove leading and trailing spaces in string. [item](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_items.asp) returns a 2d array with each row containing key and value.

```py
mydict = {'fruits': 'banana, apple,grapefruit',
'vegetables': 'tomato, potato,brocolli',
'dry fruits': 'cashew, almond' }
newlist = []
mylist = list(mydict.values())
for key,val in mydict.items():
    for value in val.split(','):
        newlist.append(value.strip())
print(newlist)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of *mylist*? Why *mydict.items()* when you're not interested in the keys?

Comment: you can directly use `mydict.values()`.

Comment: @AlbertWinestein question seems to be asked by a beginner. he/she can learn a new method and just storing an extra variable isn't gonna cost you a lot of space

Comment: @SharimIqbal Ofcourse I can

Comment: @AlbertWinestein, I am using the keys as well but since the keys have only one string (and not a group of strings separated by ,)so I thought I could store it in a list by typecasting.

Comment: I am working on a project which is turning out to be a bit complicated especially because I am a beginner , so appreciate your help. Thank you all.